# In-App purchasing to remove iAds banner from iPhone/iPad apps

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios4

I am developing an App for the iPad/iPhone and I am using an AdBanner for the iPhone and AdInterstitial for iPad.

I was wondering if I need to do anything if a user purchases or will the ads just stop coming in?

Basically, I wanted to know if I need to track a purchase version without ads, vs a free version with ads?  And if I need to do that, what is the best way of doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course this won't happen magically.

Don't include the code that shows the ads if you have a separate "pro version".
Or if you offer In-App-Purchase put a `if ([self isFreeVersion])` where you show the ads. And of course you have add code so the IAP changes the BOOL returned by isFreeVersion.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought. I need to manage it myself.  Thanks for the input.